# jquery: how use sumbit() functions in click() event?

Tags: hyperlink, submit

How use submit and ajax functions on click event? I need send input hidden to server using a link but no found in click event.... any solution? please help!

p.d. sorry for my english xd

```
     $('#delete_link').click(function() {


                           $('#myform').submit(function() {

                                if ($('#codigo').val().length < 1) {$('#notice').html('Error'); return false; }

                                $.ajax({   
                                      type: "POST",   
                                      url: 'mantenimiento.php?action=Eliminar',  

                                      data: $(this).serialize(),   
                                      success: function(data) {

                                            switch(data){
                                                case 'success':
                                                    window.location.reload();
                                                    break;
                                                default:
                                                    $('#notice').html('<p class="error">'+data+'<\/p>');
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                      }   
                                });
                                return false;
                            });

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this bit:

```
$('#delete_link').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
```

is only binding the function to the `submit` event on #myform (when `#delete_link` is clicked), but doesn't actually trigger the event.

I think what you want is something like:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  // stuff to do when submit
});
$('#delete_link').click(function() {
    $('#myform').trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: Thanks sbeam, I solved my problem with your example. Thank you very much!.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a handler to the `submit` event which makes your AJAX request.

You need to make the AJAX request directly, without involving the `submit` evemt.